# Create Dataframe from a nested dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dask

I am trying to create a dataframe from a list of values which has nested dictionaries So this is my data

```
 d=[{'user': 200,
 'p_val': {'a': 10, 'b': 200},
 'f_val': {'a': 20, 'b': 300},
 'life': 8},
  {'user': 202,
 'p_val': {'a': 100, 'b': 200},
 'f_val': {'a': 200, 'b': 300},
 'life': 8}]
```

i am trying to turn it into a dataframe as follows:

```
user new_col f_val   p_val life
200   a        20     10    8
200   b        300    200   8
202   a        200    100   8
202   b        300    200   8
```

I looked at other answers, none of them matched my requirement.
The nearest I could find was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53892083/4859139), and still did not work me.
Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(e) for e in d])
df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'newcol'})

newcol  user    p_val   f_val   life
0   a   200 10  20  8
1   b   200 200 300 8
2   a   202 100 200 8
3   b   202 200 300 8
```

The first line makes a DataFrame with the index being the `a` and `b` values. The second line makes this the `newcol` column.

Comment: Brilliant! `pd.concat(map(pd.DataFrame, d))`